# Error setting up virtualenv for existing Django project

Tags: django, virtualenv

I grabbed the source for a project I want to play with and I'm trying to setup virtualenv. The command I run is:

```
. virtualenv
```

which results in:

```
__requires__: command not found
The program 'import' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
from: can't read /var/mail/pkg_resources
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: line 8: `    sys.exit('
```

This is with Python 2.7.1 and virtualenv works with my other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `python virtualenv` or `./virtualenv` instead. `. virtualenv` will try to import and execute a Python script as a shell script.

Comment: Thanks! "virtualenv ." was what I needed, I was doing the opposite.